# Django ORM returns all data in many-to-many key relationship

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am facing this problem when i apply .filter() on Django model it return all the sales data which i dont want, I am trying to filter data based on date and want data of the entered date only

Sales Model:

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    Amount = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    Date = models.DateField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    VAT = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Machine Model:

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Sales = models.ManyToManyField(Sales, blank=True)
    ......
```

API:

```
class MachineDateData(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        target_date = date(2023, 5, 1)
        data = Machine.objects.filter(id=524).filter(Sales__Date=target_date)
        serializer = MachineReadOnlySerializer(data, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Serializer:

```
class MachineReadOnlySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Machine
        depth = 1
        fields = ('id','name', 'Sales')
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 524,
        "name": "RÃ©sidhome Marseille Saint Charles ",
        "Sales": [
            {
                "id": 67274,
                "Amount": 45.12327285161129,
                "Date": "2023-05-01",
                "updated_at": "2023-07-29T19:08:07.702463Z",
                "VAT": false
            },
            {
                "id": 67275,
                "Amount": 43.24381640146215,
                "Date": "2023-05-02",
                "updated_at": "2023-07-29T19:08:07.725326Z",
                "VAT": false
            },
            {
                "id": 67276,
                "Amount": 85.53046658140136,
                "Date": "2023-05-03",
                "updated_at": "2023-07-29T19:08:07.747431Z",
                "VAT": false
            },
...more results here
}
]
```

I am looking for a result that looks like this, Inner join to both tables, I have tried to on SQL and on SQL it works fine and shows result, but in Django ORM it does show all the data

```
[
    {
        "id": 524,
        "name": "RÃ©sidhome Marseille Saint Charles ",
        "Sales": [
            {
                "id": 67274,
                "Amount": 45.12327285161129,
                "Date": "2023-05-01",
                "updated_at": "2023-07-29T19:08:07.702463Z",
                "VAT": false
            }           
        ]
    }
]
```

SQL query

```
select * from Machine_machine mm INNER JOIN  Machine_machine_Sales as mms on mm.id = mms.machine_id INNER JOIN Machine_sales Ms on mms.sales_id = Ms.id where Date ='2023-05-01';
```

SQL query on (data. Query)

```
SELECT "Machine_machine"."id", "Machine_machine"."name", "Machine_machine"."Modem", "Machine_machine"."Picture", "Machine_machine"."IMEI", "Machine_machine"."Telemetry_Unit_Firmware", "Machine_machine"."Manufacturer_Model", "Machine_machine"."Serial_No", "Machine_machine"."Machine_type_id", "Machine_machine"."FW", "Machine_machine"."Protocol", "Machine_machine"."Connection_Method", "Machine_machine"."Data_usage_last_month", "Machine_machine"."Data_overspend_last_month", "Machine_machine"."Power", "Machine_machine"."Network", "Machine_machine"."Sim_Status", "Machine_machine"."Communication", "Machine_machine"."Signal", "Machine_machine"."Active", "Machine_machine"."Location_id" FROM "Machine_machine" INNER JOIN "Machine_machine_Sales" ON ("Machine_machine"."id" = "Machine_machine_Sales"."machine_id") INNER JOIN "Machine_sales" ON ("Machine_machine_Sales"."sales_id" = "Machine_sales"."id") WHERE ("Machine_machine"."id" = 524 AND "Machine_sales"."Date" = 2023-05-01) ORDER BY "Machine_machine"."id" ASC
```

Comment: You use ```Sales__Date``` but in your query you use ```Date```, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, in SQL i passed date, as i was using that table directly

Comment: What query is Django using? i.e. if you add `print(data.query)` to your Django view, what SQL does that show?

Comment: Added query in question @NickODell

Answer (score 0):

Check your object data first. I think the object has multiple Sales value relationship.

```py
machine = Machine.objects.filter(id=524)
print(machine.Sales.all())
```

If it exists then remove the unwanted data and keep only the required one.

Comment: This is one possible way, but if the data is too big, then it would take more time. SQL query takes lesser time,

Answer (score 0):

After 4 days I was able to figure out the a better approach to solve this question!

```
Machine.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('Sales', queryset=Sales.objects.filter(Date__month=7,Date__year=2023)))
```

the value in filter can be changed based on what values are used for data filtering

Dataset now:

```
[
{
    "id": 517,
    "name": "PULV - Nanterre (R+1 CafÃ©)",
    "Sales": [
        {
            "id": 105487,
            "Amount": 1.6527446398663428,
            "Date": "2023-07-01",
            "updated_at": "2023-07-29T19:27:15.635027Z",
            "VAT": false
        },
        {
            "id": 105488,
            "Amount": 67.29903784065506,
            "Date": "2023-07-02",
            "updated_at": "2023-07-29T19:27:15.657534Z",
            "VAT": true
        },
```